# Как реализовать Key-Value Observer

Tags: ios, ios7

Надо реализовать превью текста в `UITableViewCell`. Размер и тип шрифта меняются в других ячейках таблицы и хранятся в синглтоне.

`[Settings sharedSettings].fontName` и `[Settings sharedSettings].fontSize`

Как реализовать это с помощью `Key-Value Observing`? Не знаю как задать `forKeyPath`

Что написано сейчас: подписываюсь на изменение значения переменной в методе `init` `UITableViewController`-а

```
[self addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"fontName"
              options:0
              context:NULL];
```

обрабатываю изменение

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"fontName"]) {
        NSLog(@"Observer is working!!!");
    }

    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                         ofObject:object
                           change:change
                          context:context];
}
```

отписываюсь от KVO

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeObserver:self
              forKeyPath:@"fontName"];
}
```

Comment: Возможно оно не заходит в тот самый `init`?

Comment: Заходит, проверил через `NSLog`

Comment: Вы понимаете, что следите за свойством fontName контролера UITableViewController, а не синглтона Settings? Так и задумано?

Comment: @ruman не знаю как задать `forKeyPath`, думаю что проблема только в этом. Как его задавать?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел ошибку, надо заменить

```
[self addObserver:self...
```

на

```
[[Settings sharedSettings] addObserver:self..
```

так же нужно убрать

```
[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPat...
```

иначе событие `observeValueForKeyPath` считается не обработанным.